# Array Concatenate text and variable

Tags: arrays, vba, concatenation

I would like to create an array as follows:

```
Dim vHdr As Variant

vHdr = Array("Jogo", "Sala", "Operadora", "Semana", "NSemana", "Acumulado Semana 3")
```

However, in "Acumulado Semana 3", the 3 is a variable called semana_atual.

I tried:

```
vHdr = Array("Jogo", "Sala", "Operadora", "Semana", "NSemana", ""Acumulado & "" - "" & " & semana_atual")
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You should tag your question with what this actually is (i.e. what tool or language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this (for VBA):

```
vHdr = Array("Jogo", "Sala", "Operadora", "Semana", "NSemana", "Acumulado Semana " & semana_atual)
```

just you need some order with your quotation marks. (I added 'Semana' referring to what you need, not what you have tried).